# Why does a bash here-string add a trailing newline char?

Tags: bash, text-processing

The following examples show that a newline is added to a *here-string*.
Why is this done?

```
xxd -p <<<'a'  
# output: 610a

xxd -p <<<'a
'
# output: 610a0a
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The easy answer is because ksh is written that way (and bash is compatible). But there's a reason for that design choice.

Most commands expect text input. In the unix world, [a text file consists of a sequence of lines, each ending in a newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file/18789#18789). So in most cases a final newline is required. An especially common case is to grab the output of a command with a command susbtitution, process it in some way, then pass it to another command. The command substitution strips final newlines; `<<<` puts one back.

```
tmp=$(foo)
tmp=${tmp//hello/world}
tmp=${tmp#prefix}
bar <<<$tmp
```

Bash and ksh can't manipulate binary data anyway (it can't cope with null characters), so it's not surprising that their facilities are geared towards text data.

The `<<<` here-string syntax is mostly only for convenience anyway, like `<<` here-documents. If you need to not add a final newline, use `echo -n` (in bash) or `printf` and a pipeline.

Comment: Much more thorough than my answer.

Comment: Bash may have borrowed here-strings from ksh93, but ksh in turn borrowed them from zsh, which got them from the Plan 9 shell *rc*.

Comment: `<<<` was introduced to the Bourne world by `zsh`, not `ksh`. And it was inspired by a similar operator in the Unix port of `rc` which did _not_ add that extra newline character. Interestingly, the `=(<<<text)` operator doesn't add that newline in `zsh`.

Comment: If you wonder about the interest in this answer is because of [this question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37728699/1983854).

Comment: Is there any way to write the here-string (without using any other utility like `printf`, etc) avoiding the tailing newline in `bash`? Like @StéphaneChazelas pointed is possible in `zsh`.

Comment: @CTodea If you want to avoid a pipe operator, you can use `< <(echo -n …)`. This doesn't use any external utility either (`echo` is a builtin, and so is `printf`). But it does basically the same thing as `echo -n … |` (same number of processes, same impact on error handling) and it's rather less readable.

Comment: Maybe a link to manual to back it up  would be useful https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings

Answer (score 5):

One scenario in which it is practical to have newlines appended to here-strings is when using the `read` command when `set -e` mode is active.  Recall that `set -e` causes a script to terminate when it (more or less) encounters statements that generate a non-zero status code.  Consider that `read` generates a non-zero status code when it encounters a string without newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# The following statement succeeds because here-strings append a newline:
IFS='' read -r <<< 'newline appended'
echo 'Made it here'

# The following statement fails because 'read' returns a non-zero status
# code when no newlines are encountered.
printf 'no newline' | IFS='' read -r
echo 'Did not make it here'
```

Answer (score -4):

I think that's the only way to get a newline at the end of a here-string, proof:

```
xxd <<<`echo -ne "a\n"`
```

It would appear that the here-string operator strips newlines unless they are given in the syntax you submitted.

Comment: It's the command substitution that's stripping the final newline. You could simplify this to `xxd <<<$(echo a)`.