# How to remove new line added by readarray when using a delimiter?

Tags: bash, bash-array

```
VAR=a,b,c,d
# VAR=$(echo $VAR|tr -d '\n')
echo "[$VAR]"
readarray -td, ARR<<< "$VAR"
declare -p ARR
```

Result:

```
[a,b,c,d]
declare -a ARR=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]=$'d\n')
```

How can I tell `readarray` not to add the final newline `\n`? What is the meaning of the latest `$` symbol?

Comment: Re:[_`"What is the meaning of the latest $ symbol?" `_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The implicit trailing new-line character is *not* added by the `readarray` builtin, but by the here-string (`<<<`) of `bash`, see [Why does a bash here-string add a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20157/112235). You can get rid of that by printing the string without the new-line using `printf` and read it over a process-substitution technique `< <()`

```
readarray -td, ARR < <(printf '%s' "$VAR")
declare -p ARR
```

would properly generate now

```
declare -a ARR=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d")
```

Comment: Wow! I would have never found this. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could use split+glob (what happens when you leave an expansion unquoted in list contexts). It gets in our way most of the time, it would be a shame not to use it when we actually need it:

```
IFS=,
set -o noglob

ARR=($VAR) # split+glob with glob disabled, and split using , as delimiter
```

That's a bit less convoluted than writing a temp file and then call `readarray` on it like in the `readarray <<< "$string"` approach (also note that `readarray -d` needs a very recent version of `bash`).

Note that despite the `S` in `IFS` (which stands for *separator*), that works the same way as `readarray` in that `a,,b,` is split into `"a"`, `""` and `"b"` only.

For a real splitting operator, you could use `zsh` instead:

```
ARR=("${(@s:,:)VAR}")
```

(the `@` and double quotes to preserve the empty elements).

Comment: The `readarray <<< "$string"` writes to a tempp file and then deletes it instead of using the memory?

Comment: @user1156544 Yes.

Comment: How can I do something similar to your last command in bash? I am using bash 3.3 and trying to compensate the lack of `readarray -d`

Answer (score 4):

A canned version of @StéphaneChazelas' answer:

```
# usage: setarray varname sep string
setarray(){ declare -n a=$1; local IFS=$2 -; set -f; a=($3); }

$ setarray arr , 1,2,3,
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")

$ setarray path : "$PATH"
$ setarray ld_preload ': ' "$LD_PRELOAD" # its elements can be separated by either ':' or spaces
...
```

The `local -` will make options like `set -f` (`noglob`) local to the function, just as variables.

The `declare -n a=$1` will create a *local* variable `a` as an alias to the global variable named by `$1` (the first argument to the function).