# Why this loop is executed for an empty set?

Tags: bash, find, here-document

Create an empty directory, then run this code:

```
find /empty_directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d |
while read dir;
do
    echo "Simple find: $dir"
done

printf '%s\n' '-----'                   # Safer than    echo -----

while read dir;
do
    echo "HereDoc find: $dir"
done <<< "$(find /empty_directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)"
```

This is the output:

```
-----
HereDoc find:
```

In other words, the second loop gets executed once with an empty variable.

Why is it so? How can I make the second loop behave correctly and not run when there is no directory found to be looped over?

Comment: Related: [Why does a bash here-string add a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char)

Answer (score 5):

#### What’s happening?

I understand that you’re trying to solve a particular problem,
but one of the first rules of debugging is to simplify the scenario. 
If we do

```bash
$ sleep 1 | read x
$ echo "$?"
1

$ read x <<< $(sleep 1)
$ echo "$?"
0
```

we see that a `read` from an empty pipe fails,
but a `read` from a null here string succeeds (reading a null value). 
That is what you are seeing.

And it’s spelled out in [bash(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION):

> **Here Strings**
>
>   A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> `[n]<<<word`
>
> The *`word`* undergoes tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,
> command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal. 
> Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed. 
> The result is supplied as a single string, ***with a newline appended**,*
> to the command on its standard input
> (or file descriptor *`n`* if *`n`* is specified).

(emphasis added)

Bash turns a null here string into a blank line, not an EOF.

#### How to fix it?

**The obvious — modify the loop logic:**

```
while read dir  && [ "$dir" != "" ]
do
    echo "HereDoc find: $dir"
done <<< "$(find /empty_directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)"
```

This terminates the loop if it reads a blank line.

**Equally obvious — modify the logic *in* the loop:**

```
while read dir
do
    if [ "$dir" = "" ]; then continue; fi
    echo "HereDoc find: $dir"
done <<< "$(find /empty_directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)"
```

This ignores blank lines (but doesn’t terminate the loop).

**Perhaps better — modify the redirection:**

```
while read dir
do
    echo "HereDoc find: $dir"
done < <(find /empty_directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

By using process substitution
(`<(command)`)
and simple redirection (**`<`**) instead of command substitution
(`$(command)`)
and a here string (**`<<<`**), you prevent Bash from adding the newline.

P.S. Note that you don’t need to have a semicolon (`;`)
at the end of a line, as you have done with `while read dir`.