# How to make bash not assign a \n to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a variable that goes more or less like this:

```
$ echo "$LIST"
file1: ok
file2: ok
file3:
file4:
file5: ok
```

Then I need to get the list of files that are not ok:

```
$ sed '/:\s.\+$/d' <<< "$LIST"
file3:
file4:
```

That works file, but in the event that there is no file that are not ok in the list, this will happen:

```
$ echo "$LIST"
file1: ok
file2: ok
file3: ok
file4: ok
file5: ok
$ sed '/:\s.\+$/d' <<< "$LIST"
$ NEWLIST=$(sed '/:\s.\+$/d' <<< "$LIST")
$ echo "$NEWLIST"

$ cat -A <<< "$NEWLIST"
$
$ wc -l <<< "$NEWLIST"
1
$ wc -c <<< "$NEWLIST"
1
```

This newline (I think that is a \n) added to the variable is making a mess on my program as it identifies as having one file listed because I use `wc -l` to know how many files exist there. I'm not entirely sure if the \n is assigned by bash or by sed. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20162/108618

Comment: I think the undesirable newlines are already present in your `$LIST` variable.  They are what makes each file's text appear on its own line when you do `echo "$LIST"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to exclude `ok` items, you could do this:

```
grep -cv ': ok$' <<< "$LIST"
```

Or similarly, but broadly opposite

```
grep -c ':$' <<< "$LIST"
```

EDIT: based on comment from @ilkkachu

If the list is entirely empty the `-vc` variant will erroneously report a count of 1, due to a `<<<` behaviour.

You could either add a guard to detect an empty LIST or simply use pipe instead

```
printf "%s" "$LIST" | grep -vc ": ok$"
```

If the list could contain blank lines they would also cause a miscount when using `-vc`.

In either case a further modification could be applied to prevent miscounting.

```
grep -vcE "^$|: ok$"
```

But now we are starting to jump through hoops and thus making the code harder to understand.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I don't see grep -c counting the here-string extra empty line. This worked like a charm. In your example it counts as 3 because you did add an extra line with your second \n

Comment: You raise some valid edge cases @ikkachu, answer updated.

Comment: what am I missing here. Your original response was correct. It was not going to report with if the list is empty. Now after you edit it, your answer is wrong. The `grep -c` was just perfect in my case.

Comment: My edit was just to address a technically correct issue highlighted with the `-vc` variant (though perhaps not relevant with your data). I'd agree that the `-c` variant would be preferable, and this is still included in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A here-string `<<<` adds a newline at the end of the string before passing it to the command, and a command substitution removes any trailing newlines after reading the output of the command inside.

Also, `echo` adds a trailing newline to what it prints, but that's not a major issue here.

So, let's say you have one complete line in the variable, with the newline at the end, so the string is `file1: ok<nl>`

Now, you run `sed '/ok/d' <<< "$LIST"`, and here, `sed` gets the input `file1: ok<nl><nl>`. It removes any lines that contain `ok`, and outputs the empty line `<nl>`.

You capture that with a command substitution, which removes the trailing newlines, giving the empty string. That's then assigned to `NEWLIST`.

Then, `echo "$NEWLIST"` prints a single newline (because `echo` adds one), and `wc -l <<< "$NEWLIST"` gives a single newline as input to `wc` (because the here-string adds one).

You'd get the same end result if the variable was initially just `file1: ok`, without the trailing newline, just the command substitution would have no newlines to remove from the end of the output of sed.

All of that means both command substitutions and here-strings mostly work well for single-line values, where you might not want the newline to appear in a variable but often do want to provide any commands with a complete line as input. As you saw, they do work for multiline-strings too (if the final newlines is again missing from the variable), but the odd dropping and adding of the  newline still happens. It breaks down in the case where there is no newline to remove.

To see why that juggling is done, note that if command substitution didn't remove the newline from the output of `date` here, this would print a newline just before the period at the end, breaking the line in the middle.

```
$ weekday=$(date +%A)
$ echo "today is a $weekday."
today is a Thursday.
```

---

The simplest workaround is likely to just store multiline data like that in files instead. With `inputfile` containing the five lines (with the appropriate newlines):

```
file1: ok
file2: ok
file3: ok
file4: ok
file5: ok
```

then:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
sed -e '/ok/d' < inputfile > "$tmpfile"
wc -l < "$tmpfile"
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

outputs `0`.

(Note that neither `\s` or `\+` is standard POSIX basic or extended regex syntax, so they don't work on all systems, e.g. with the `sed` on macOS. That's why I used just `/ok/` above.)

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for the answer. But I would rather avoid working with files at this point, bxm above gave an answer that is quite interesting, using grep -c

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not entirely sure if the \n is assigned by bash or by sed.

It is neither at this point. You can check it with for example

```
$ echo -n "$NEWLIST"  # echo without -n adds a newline
$ wc -l <<< ""
1
$ wc -c <<< ""
1
```

It is the `echo` which is intentionally printing your variable (which is empty) and ends with a newline and for the here-string Bash ensures that it ends with a newline because tools tend to behave surprising if the last line is not ending with a \n.

The simplest way to fix it is probably to just check if NEWLIST is empty. Alternatively work more with files directly. For example:

```
list_file="$(mktemp)"
new_list_file="$(mktemp)"

# cleanup
trap 'rm "$list_file" "$new_list_file"' EXIT

echo "$LIST" > "$list_file"
sed '/:\s.\+$/d' "$list_file" > "$new_list_file"
wc -l "$new_list_file"
# or wc -l < "$new_list_file" if you want to prevent it from printing the filename
```

For an example of an unexpected result if here-string would not add a newline think what result you expect from the following command and then run it:

```
echo -n "Content" | wc -l
```

> Answer is: 0

Comment: How would you explain `wc` case?

Comment: Which `wc` case? The `wc -c <<< ""`? The here-string adds an implicit newline so the input has one character, the \n.

Comment: @PaulPazderski, so, why are you saying the newline is due to "neither" Bash or sed, when you know the shell adds a newline at the end of a here-string?

Comment: @ilkkachu Was a bit unprecise there. Adriano_epifas assumed that the error happens around the sed command and with my "at this point" I meant that none of the sed invocations introduced the unwanted newline and in fact neither the LIST nor NEWLIST variable had an unwanted newline. In the end here-string is part of Bash so you could say Bash adds the newline.

Comment: @PaulPazderski, I did mention it could be bash doing that. But more than that, using echo -n is not a solution because if my list has 1 item only, it will show as "0" since the last /n is suppressed. echo -n messes up the result regardless the number of items in the variable

Comment: @Adriano_epifas your right. Will adapt the answer. Well then you can simply add a `[[ -n "$NEWLIST" ]]` to check if it was not empty or work more with files: `echo "$LIST" > list.tmp; sed '/:\s.\+$/d' list.tmp > newlist.tmp; wc -l newlist.tmp`

Comment: ikkachu below did suggest working with files, but bmx above suggested using grep -c that works just fine