# Should I end my text/script files with a newline?

Tags: linux, files, standard, posix, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point in adding a new line to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file)

What is considered better behaviour: to leave the last letter of the last line to be the last byte of a file, or to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end to let there be a `lf`? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Copied from my comment on the question, as requested.)

See [Why should files end with a newline? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline). The "TL;DR": [POSIX says so](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_205), and it's pretty logical to have a line end in and end-of-line character.

See the linked Stack Overflow question for practical consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I always put an empty line at the end.  I think it looks cleaner, and some programs choke on the last line if there isn't a newline.

Comment: An empty line at the end means that the file ends in two newline characters. If the file ends with a single newline character, it means the last line is not empty; the newline terminates that last line.

Comment: @Gilles If you want to be pedantic about it, then I what I meant was "newline".  I just said "blank line" because that's the way it displays in every text editor.

Comment: Most unix editors do not display a blank line below a file that ends with a newline. That's not just pedantry, it's [how most unix programs work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that vim adds a newline at the end of the last line automatically.

Comment: @Kevin Just think of lines in a text file as *records*, then it's pretty logical. Pressing Enter means "begin editing a new record". When written to disk, the items in this list of lines are interspersed with newline characters. (Note that more translation is going on: Characters also must be encoded from the internal representation, for example to UTF-8)