# How to edit authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh, authorization

What is the best method for editing the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

I mean if I need to append a new key to my `authorized_keys` file, than what are the best methods to do that?

Answer (score 15):

Try just to edit the file and paste key on the end.
You want automated? Try from server where you want to add key to do:

```
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub login@hostname
```

You can always try `ssh-add` on the server where you have an `authorized_keys` file stored.

Plenty of opportunities :D

Comment: Also `cat keyfile >>authorized_keys`

Comment: What should go as `hostname` ?

Answer (score 0):

Each line is an independent entry.  You can grep them to filter,  `sed -i~ /pattern/d authorized_keys` to delete lines, say all those from some server, or `cat new-entries >> authorized_keys` to add lines to the end.

Comment: there is two problem with "cat new-entries >> authk.

Comment: 1) people could mistype ">>" to ">" so the file is gone..

Comment: 2) if there isn't any newline char in the authorized_keys file, then cat/echo will append the new public key to the end of the last line... :\

Comment: The `cat` method is the one most frequently used and suggested.  If it doesn't end in a newline, [it's not a well-formed text file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file).

Comment: @Lance: Wrt. 1, I can't say I've ever done that, but if you are prone to this kind of thing, try using `sed -i~ 'r$ new-entries'`, since that creates a backup file.  Wrt. 2., this is easily enough fixed with a text editor, and as Kevin says, you should pay a bit of attention to the semantics of what you are doing.