# How do I stop sed from adding extra newline characters

Tags: sed

I am running the following 2 `sed` commands. The first one adds newline characters where I want them, the second also adds newline characters where I want them, BUT also adds an extra one at the end of the file where there wasn't one before.

```
sed -e 's|\<LIST_G_STATEMENT>|&\
|g' ${XMLDIR}/statement_tmp_1.xml > ${XMLDIR}/statement_tmp_2.xml

sed -e 's|\</LIST_G_STATEMENT>|&\
|g' ${XMLDIR}/statement_tmp_2.xml > ${XMLDIR}/statement_tmp_3.xml
```

Using `od -c` on all 3 of the files gives the following output.

statement_tmp_1.xml (no `\n` at end of file)

```
1314700    T   A   T   E   M   E   N   T   >   <   /   L   I   S   T   _
1314720    G   _   S   T   A   T   E   M   E   N   T   >   <   /   G   _
1314740    S   E   T   U   P   >   <   /   L   I   S   T   _   G   _   S
1314760    E   T   U   P   >   <   /   A   R   X   S   G   P   O   >
1314777
```

statement_tmp_2.xml (no `\n` at end of file)

```
1314700    S   T   A   T   E   M   E   N   T   >   <   /   L   I   S   T
1314720    _   G   _   S   T   A   T   E   M   E   N   T   >   <   /   G
1314740    _   S   E   T   U   P   >   <   /   L   I   S   T   _   G   _
1314760    S   E   T   U   P   >   <   /   A   R   X   S   G   P   O   >
1315000
```

statement_tmp_3.xml (`\n` at end of file - where did it come from?)

```
1314700    S   T   A   T   E   M   E   N   T   >   <   /   L   I   S   T
1314720    _   G   _   S   T   A   T   E   M   E   N   T   >  \n   <   /
1314740    G   _   S   E   T   U   P   >   <   /   L   I   S   T   _   G
1314760    _   S   E   T   U   P   >   <   /   A   R   X   S   G   P   O
1315000    >  \n
1315002
```

I am running AIX 5.3

Basically, I either want it to stop adding the extra `\n`, or find a way of removing it.

Comment: Just a question: why are you using a literal newline in your substitution pattern when you could have used `s|...|&\n|` just as well?

Comment: @JosephR. `\n` in the right hand side is not portable.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas That's weird. Is it a CR vs CRLF thing?

Comment: A file which doesn't end in a newline character is not a text file, so the behaviour with text utilities on them is _unspecified_. Use `perl` or other tool that can deal with binary data.

Comment: @JosephR. No, `\<LF>` is the traditional and POSIX way to add a LF character. `\n` would typically substitute a `n` character in anything but GNU `sed`.

Comment: @JosephR, it was taken from another forum. I think I tried the \n, which works on the Linux side, but doesn't appear to work in AIX

Comment: I don't know how to make your AIX sed behave, but `head -c -1` can bite off the final newline.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner, neither `-c` nor negative numbers are POSIX. [AIX head](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/head.htm) supports `-c` as an extension, but not negative numbers.

Comment: `sed` and other text utilities work on [text files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file/18789#18789). A non-empty file that doesn't end in a newline is not a text file. Why are you trying to work with a non-text file?

Answer (score 13):

You should consider yourself lucky that AIX `sed` added that missing newline characters.

A non-empty file that doesn't end in a newline character is not a text file (at least as per the POSIX definition of a text file) as a text file is meant to contain lines and lines are a (not-too-long) sequence of characters terminated by a newline character, so the behaviour of text utilities like `sed` on it is unspecified and in practice varies from implementation to implementation.

Some `sed` implementation would have dismissed those spurious character after the last line.

AFAIK, `xml` files are meant to be text files, so that means `sed` just fixed it for you.

If you do need that file not to end in a newline character, then you could use `perl` or other tools that can cope with non-text data.

```
perl -pe 's|<LIST_G_STATEMENT>|$&\n|g'
```

Comment: The terminating newline _is_ helpful, if you expect to pipe your `sed` output into any other standard Unix utility. Honestly, I didn't notice `sed` did this for _years_, since Bourne shell command substitutions like `$(sed 's/bas/replac/' <<<'basement')` furtively trim the final newline, if there is one. But there _are_ times when you definitely don't want it; _e.g._, manipulating X clipboard text with `sed`. FYI, GNU sed, if available, does not add a terminating newline if you use `p` it with the `-n` option, as described in [this SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493477/278323).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to remove the final newline from a file using `dd`:

```
printf "" | dd  of='/path/to/file' seek=<filesize_in_bytes - 1> bs=1 count=1
```

To test whether a file ends with a newline you could use:

```
tail -c 1 /path/to/file | tr -dc '\n' | wc -c
```

And to get the file size in bytes use:

```
wc -c < /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [AIX manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/tail.htm) IBM's `tail` does `-r`everse - which looks pretty cool. So long as your file is under 20KB the following should work:

```
tail -r <file | dd bs=1 skip=1 | tail -r >file.new
```