# sed behaves different on FreeBSD and on Linux?

Tags: sed, freebsd

I use both Linux and FreeBSD (specifically, I use Debian Linux and PC-BSD), and I found something weird about `sed`.

I frequently need to convert "tab separated values" files to "comma separated values". The simplest way I know is to use `sed`, like this:

```
sed 's/\t/,/g' inputFile.txt > outputFile.csv
```

This works perfectly on Linux: It replaces every tab with a comma... but on FreeBSD, it doesn't replace anything!!!

Am I missing something? Is there a syntax with FreeBSD `sed` that is different to the one on Linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you should use the `-E` option(or `-r` as explained [on the manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=1&n=1)) to keep compatibility with GNU Sed. In your case, you could install Gnu Sed if you are used to it (port [gsed](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gsed&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) on FreeBSD), or it will take a long effort to port scripts.

And remember. If some command on BSD does not act like the gnu version of that utility, it doesn´t mean it´s broken ;)

Comment: Thank you. The `-E` option makes the trick (both on FreeBSD and on Mac OS X).

Comment: On my FreeBSD 9 the -E option does not help.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are various differences, the [behavior of `-i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/22222) being the only one I know of off the top of my head.

I've never used BSD so I can't really help with the details but a workaround might be to use `tr` instead:

```
tr '\t' , < inputFile.txt > outputFile.csv
```

A pleasant side effect is that `tr` should be significantly faster. I tested that on my Linux using a test file with 50000 lines, each of which had 2 tabs:

```
$ time tr '\t' , < foo.txt > /dev/null 

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time sed 's/\t/,/g' foo.txt > /dev/null 

real    0m0.039s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: `tr '\t' ,` is more portable than `tr $'\t' ,`. `tr '[\t]' '[,]'` would even be portable to some old SysV systems.

Comment: tab is the default delimiter for `cut`. The POSIX spec for `tr` is [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html). I was wrong about `[` needed for old SysV. As that POSIX spec points out `[` is only needed for ranges there.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas so it is, sorry not sure what I'm confusing it with then. Thanks for the clarification in any case.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, unlike GNU `sed` FreeBSD `sed` does not interpret ANSI C escape sequences such as `\t` in regular expressions.

One way to get a least common denomiator in this case is to use `printf`.

```
tab="$(printf '\t')"
printf '\t\n' | sed 's/'"${tab}"'/,/g'
printf '\t\n' | sed 's/'"$(printf '\t')"'/,/g'
```

The behaviour of `sed -i` for in-place file edits can be made compatible if a switch or option immediately follows the `-i` switch, e. g. `sed -i -e 's/x/X/g' file` works for both GNU `sed` as well as FreeBSD `sed`.

Recent versions of FreeBSD `sed` (FreeBSD 8.1 or newer) have the `-r` switch to increase compatibility with GNU `sed`.

(In addition, the use of POSIX character classes in `sed` regular expressions is a good way to ensure compatibility as well).

For an alternative, POSIX-conformant `sed` implementation see: [minised - a smaller, cheaper, faster SED implementation](http://www.exactcode.de/site/open_source/minised/).

Answer (score 3):

You should use a literal <kbd>TAB</kbd> character instead of `\t`:

```
sed 's/    /,/g' inputFile.txt > outputFile.csv
```

See [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98801/how-do-i-stop-sed-from-adding-extra-newline-characters#comment150577_98801) by Stephane on another question.

The following article may also interest you:

- [The Differences in Sed Versions](http://www.ehow.com/info_8104681_differences-sed-versions.html)

I quote the relevant part:

> **Regex Differences**
>   
>   Regular expression syntax differs subtly between the different versions of SED. Most of the differences involve special escape patterns used to match non-printing characters, such as the ASCI bell and form feeds.

Answer (score 0):

After login I see the next announcement and save it. Hope it will useful for other too

> Want to use sed(1) to edit a file in place?  Well, to replace every
>   'e' with an 'o', in a file named 'foo', you can do:
>
> ```
> sed -i.bak s/e/o/g foo
> ```
>
> And you'll get a backup of the original in a file named 'foo.bak', but
>   if you want no backup:
>
> ```
> sed -i '' s/e/o/g foo
> ```

Comment: the `-i` option was [covered already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102769/117549), though