# Get text between a word and the last line?

Tags: text-processing, sed

According to the answers in Stack Overflow question *[How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469)*, we can get text between two words:

```
sed -n "/first/,/second/p" file
```

But what if I want to get text between a word and the last line of the file, as in the following?

```
sed -n "/word/,/lastline/p" file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including the last line you'd do:

```
sed -n '/word/,$p'
```

That matches the first occurrence of `word` all the way until the last line and prints all matches.

Not including the last line:

```
sed '/word/,$!d;$d'
```

...which deletes *negated* matches and then deletes the last line.

And to get from only the last match to the last line you have to try a little harder:

```
 sed -e :n -e '/\n.*word/D;N;$q;bn'
```

It loops - it never completes the normal `sed` line cycle but instead appends the next input line to the pattern space buffer and `b`ranches back to do so again. But when it has at least two lines in pattern space and the last matches *word* it deletes everything in the buffer but the line that matches *word*. On the last line it just `quits` and breaks the loop. So what gets printed is everything from the last occurring line containing *word* to the last line.

Hmmm... maybe I made that harder than it has to be:

```
sed 'H;$x;/word/h;$!d'
```

With that one every line is appended to hold space. But lines matching *word* then *overwrite* hold space. Every line in pattern space that is not the last line is deleted. And on the last line, just after it is appended to hold space, the hold and pattern spaces are exchanged *(in case the last line also contains word)* and everything from the last time *word* overwrote hold space is printed.

Comment: Is this one supposed to remove the last line ? `sed 'H;$x;/word/h;$!d'`

Comment: @Jidder - no, it's not supposed to, it's even supposed to retain two matches if the last line also matches. If you wanted to remove the last line you'd do instead: `sed '$x;H;/word/h;$!d'` or if you did not want two matches if the last line matches and wanted only the last line in that case: `sed 'H;/word/h;$x;$!d'`

Comment: Ahh right okay, just wondering, i need to brush up on sed :)

Comment: Or `<file tac | sed /word/q | tac` for the last `word` to end of file (like yours, assuming `word` is to be found in the file).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - yes - both of my last match versions are very likely to implode if the buffer is not refreshed. I once did this `dc` thing with its stacks that worked kind of like `tac` - it was fast, and could seemingly go forever, but I gave it up when researching the [answer to this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131225/52934) *(which, I've just realized, you also answered)* and learned that AIX `tail` can read a file backwards - and a google or two later and I met `tac`. I like it very well, but I'm also a bit of a `sed` masochist.

Answer (score 2):

Could also use awk

Including match to end of file

```
awk '/word/{x=1}x' file
```

After first match til end of file

```
awk 'x;/word/{x=1}' file
```

Comment: The first one can also be written `awk /word/,0 file`