# Gnu sed, will the p command appends a newline when printing?

Tags: sed

```
root@u1804:~# sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
root@u1804:~#
```

I'm new to sed and I created below sed's workflow based on my understanding (correct me if you find anything wrong).

[image]

So it seems the default auto printing of the pattern space will always include a newline at the end. My question is, will `p` includes a newline, too? I have below examples.

```
root@u1804:~# seq 3 | sed -rn 'p'
1
2
3
root@u1804:
```

Here the newline at the end of each number is added by sed itself (see the diagram "adds back newline to pattern space"). So it seems `p` will not append a newline. However, see below example.

```
root@u1804:~# seq 3 | sed -rn 'x;p;x;p'

1

2

3
root@u1804:~#
```

Here `x` exchange pattern space with hold space, which will result in an empty pattern space. Now `p` applies to the pattern space (nothing in it) should print nothing. But based on the result, it seems here `p` prints a newline. To me it seems this is inconsistent behavior. Can anyone  explain?

Comment: You'll probably want to add a special case for the `d` and `D` commands (and `Q` with GNU `sed`) which skip the printing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your main question:

GNU `sed` will append a `<newline>` character when executing the `p` command unless the input line was missing its terminating `<newline>` character (see the clarifications about lines below).

As far as I can tell, `sed`'s `p` flag and its auto-print feature implement the same logic to output the pattern space: if the trailing `<newline>` character was removed, they add it back; otherwise they don't.

Examples:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n%s' '4' '5' | sed ';' | hexdump -C      # auto-print
00000000  34 0a 35                                          |4.5|
00000003
```

```bash
$ printf '%s\n%s' '4' '5' | sed -n 'p;' | hexdump -C  # no auto-print; p flag
00000000  34 0a 35                                          |4.5|
00000003
```

In both cases there is no `<newline>` character (`0a`) in the output for the input lines that don't have one.

---

About your diagrams:

"Adds back newline to pattern space" is probably inaccurate because the `<newline>` character is not put *in* the pattern space<sup>1</sup>. Also, that step is not related to the `-n` option - but this does not make the diagram *wrong*; rather, it should probably be merged into "Print pattern space".
Still, I agree with you about the documentation's lack of clarity.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The sentence you quote [in your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493277/315749), "the contents of pattern space are printed out to the output stream, adding back the trailing newline if it was removed", means that the `<newline>` is appended to the stream, not to pattern space. Of course, since pattern space is cleared in a short while, this is a really minor point</sub>

---

About your tests involving the `x` flag:

Internally, pattern space and hold space are structures, and "was my trailing `<newline>` character dropped?" is a member of them. We will call it *chomped* (as it is named in `sed`'s source code, by the way).
Pattern space is filled with a read line and its *chomped* attribute depends on how that line is terminated: `true` if it ends with a `<newline>` character, `false` otherwise. On the other hand, hold space is initialized as empty and its *chomped* attributed is just set to `true`.
Therefore, when you swap pattern space and hold space and print what was born as hold and is now pattern, a `<newline>` character is printed.

Examples - these commands have the same output:

```bash
$ printf '\n' | sed -n 'p;' | hexdump -C        # input is only a <newline>
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
```

```bash
$ printf '%s' '5' | sed -n 'x;p;' | hexdump -C  # input has no <newline>
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
```

(I gave only a really brief look at `sed`'s code, so this might well be not accurate).

---

About lines (clarification started with comments to [your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493277/315749)):

It goes without saying that a *line* without a terminating `<newline>` character is a problematic concept. Quoting [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206):

> **3.206 Line**
>   A sequence of zero or more non- `<newline>` characters plus a terminating `<newline>` character.

Furthermore, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) defines a text file:

> **3.403 Text File**
>   A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. ...

Finally, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_03) on `sed` (bold mine):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>   The `sed` utility is a stream editor that shall read one or more **text files**, make editing changes according to a script of editing commands, and write the results to standard output. ...

[GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction), though, seems to be less strict when defining its input:

> `sed` is a stream editor. A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file or input from a pipeline). ...

So, relating to my first sentence, we should take into account that, for GNU `sed`, what is read into the pattern space doesn't necessarily have to be a well formed line of text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll do some testing later. One quick question, is `sed ';'` the same as `sed ''`?

Comment: I think so. I chose `;` as a short "do nothing" program, with no particular reason. I could (and probably should, for clarity) have chosen `''` as well.

Comment: This is the right answer. As to the  POSIX docs... I wonder why people are so religious about them. Often, they are lacking and this is no exception, the _DESCRIPTION_ from the `sed` manual is rather nonsensical. _"`sed` is a stream editor that shall read... files"_. Really ? Then why is it called _stream editor_ ? Because that's what it does, it edits streams - it just happens that it treats files as a stream of data... otherwise it would be called `fed` not `sed`.

Answer (score 4):

I edited my answer to only include an updated diagram based on fra-san's answer. The sole purpose is for new sed users to reference.

[image]

Comment: `sed` outputs _lines_. A line is not a line if it's not terminated by a newline character.  So the step "Adds newline", should really be incorporated into "Print pattern space" since it makes no sense to print a non-terminated line.  Likewise for reading. There is no newline character to remove since a line is terminated by it.  `sed` reads a line and puts it in the pattern space. An analogy would be having to mentally remove the dots from a text while reading it to make sense of the individual sentences.

Comment: @Kusalananda Interesting. I didn't know that before. Thanks for providing the info.

Comment: @don_crissti Looking at POSIX, it clearly says that the output from `sed` is a _text file_.  A text file is a collection of _lines_. A line is terminated by newline. It would be difficult to output a non-terminated line with standard `sed` (easy with GNU `sed`, sure).

Comment: @don_crissti You are right. This is my testing VM, so I use root. It seems I should make it a habit of using a normal user and only use root when necessary, as several people told me this. Thanks for pointing it out and looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda -  `sed`'s output is _never_ a text _file_ (unless one uses the command `w`  or the flag with the same name - in which case yes, `sed` will output to text files).

Comment: @don_crissti "The output files shall be text files whose formats are dependent on the editing commands given."  Also, the section on "STDOUT" says that `sed` writes lines.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) seems indeed to be more clear: "Whenever the pattern space is written to standard output or a named file, `sed` shall immediately follow it with a <newline>". GNU `sed`'s documentation, on the other hand, includes [footnote number 8](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#FOOT8): "Actually, if `sed` prints a line without the terminating newline, it will nevertheless print the missing newline as soon as more text is sent to the same output stream, ...".

Comment: @fra-san - exactly, the keyword here is _shall_... In theory, yes, in practice not quite...

Answer (score 1):

In GNU sed: The command `p` will add a trailing newline only if one was in the source text (one was removed from the input when placed in the pattern space) but **also** add a leading new line if additional text is printed to the same stream.

A trailing newline could be missing on the input only on the **last** line.

```
 $ printf 'abc' | od -An -c
    a   b   c                                 # no newline.

 $ printf 'abc' | sed '' | od -An -c
    a   b   c                                 # also no newline.

 $ printf 'abc' | sed -n 'p' | od -An -c
    a   b   c                                 # still no newline.

 $ printf 'abc' | sed -n 'p;p' | od -An -c
    a   b   c  \n   a   b   c                 # leading newline added.
```

Only print the last line, which will have a new line **only** if the source file already had a newline on that last line:

```
 $ printf 'abc\ndef' | sed -n '$p' | od -An -c
    d   e   f
```

From info sed:

> ---------- Footnotes ----------
>
> (1) Actually, if 'sed' prints a line without the terminating newline,
> it will nevertheless print the missing newline as soon as more text is
> sent to the same output stream, which gives the "least expected
> surprise" even though it does not make commands like 'sed -n p' exactly
> identical to 'cat'.

Some other sed versions might add a **trailing** newline and/or emit a warning.