# Can sed produce output in the form of text file(s) all by itself as long as the input came from STDIN?

Tags: sed

What the title says: assuming `sed` reads from `STDIN`<sup>1</sup> could its output be a text file ?
Just to be clear, I'm not talking about saving `sed`'s output to a text file via shell operators like `>`, `>>` or using tools like `tee` etc.
The question here is whether `sed` *alone* can produce output in the form of text file(s) and if so, under which circumstances ?

---

<sup>1: this is simply to rule out any in-place editing of a text file with implementations that support it.</sup>

Comment: If the question is about  being able to redirect `sed`'s output from within `sed` (the accepted reply suggests that), then please change the title and the text of your question to reflect it; the argument to the `w` command of `sed` doesn' t have to be a "text file"; it could be a character device, pipe, socket, etc.

Comment: @pizdelect - there's nothing to change, really: the question is whether `sed` alone can produce a text file and if so how / when does that happen. If you still don't understand it then feel free to down-vote it. If you already did so, then enjoy your vote.

Comment: Changing the question to something more relevant and precise would help people looking for info -- for instance, even the text from your comment "whether sed alone can produce (create?) a (text) file ..." is MUCH better than the one from the question ;-)

Comment: @pizdelect - if you take the time to read the question it says _exactly that_ but whatever, I'll edit it... is it better now ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using the `w` command, or the `w` flag to the `s` command, both of which are [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

For example, with

```
sed -n 'w output.txt'
```

anything fed into `sed`’s standard input will be written to `output.txt`, with no output to `sed`’s standard output (thanks to the `-n` option). This can be combined with other commands to manipulate the pattern space before writing it out.

A few notes of warning and recommendations:

If the file name starts with a blank, use a `./` prefix:

```
sed -n 'w ./ output with blanks.txt'
```

If the file name contains newline characters, POSIXly, you can escape them with backslash, though it won't work with all `sed` implementations (in particular, not with GNU `sed` nor busybox `sed`):

```
sed -n 'w ./output\
with\
newline.txt'
```

If it contains backslash characters, in some implementations (the POSIX ones above that support newlines in file names), you need to escape them with backslash:

```
sed -n 'w file\\with\\backslash.txt' # POSIX
sed -n 'w file\with\backslash.txt'   # GNU
```

Also note that the output file will be created (or truncated) even if the input is empty or the `w` command is never run like in:

```
sed 'd;w file'
```

Or

```
seq 20 | sed '/21/ w file'
```

You may want to use `awk` instead to avoid this kind of problems

```
FILE=arbitrary-file-name awk '/100/ {print > ENVIRON["FILE"]}'
```

Comment: also the `w` flag of the `s///` command. A standard `sed` can use a file name in the `r` and `w` commands or as an argument to the `w` flag of `s///`. This has security implication, because you cannot pledge the sed command as being just a filter.

Comment: See also the `W` command of GNU `sed`.

Comment: Thanks for [confirming my statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493141/gnu-sed-will-the-p-command-appends-a-newline-when-printing/493277#comment906073_493277) ! ;)