# Grep command with the side effect of adding a trailing newline character in the last line of file

Tags: grep, regular-expression, newlines

I've been doing some research on how to correctly read lines from a file whose last line may not have a trailing newline character. Have found the answer in [Read a line-oriented file which may not end with a newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418060/read-a-line-oriented-file-which-may-not-end-with-a-newline).

However, I have a second goal that is to exclude the comments at the beginning of lines and have found a [`grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) command that achieves the goal

```
$ grep -v '^ *#' file
```

But I have noticed that this command has a (for me unexpected) side behavior: it adds a trailing newline character in the last line if it does not exist

```bsh
$ cat file
# This is a commentary
aaaaaa
# This is another commentary
bbbbbb
cccccc

$ od -c file
0000000   #       T   h   i   s       i   s       a       c   o   m   m
0000020   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n   #
0000040   T   h   i   s       i   s       a   n   o   t   h   e   r
0000060   c   o   m   m   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   b   b   b   b   b
0000100   b  \n   c   c   c   c   c   c  \n
0000111

$ truncate -s -1 file

$ od -c file
0000000   #       T   h   i   s       i   s       a       c   o   m   m
0000020   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n   #
0000040   T   h   i   s       i   s       a   n   o   t   h   e   r
0000060   c   o   m   m   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   b   b   b   b   b
0000100   b  \n   c   c   c   c   c   c
0000110

$ od -c <(grep -v '^ *#' file)
0000000   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n   b   b   b   b   b   b  \n   c   c
0000020   c   c   c   c  \n
0000025
```

Notice that besides removing the line beginning comments it also adds a  trailing newline character in the last line.

How could that be?

Comment: You're about to get M. Chazelas excited again.  (-: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98809/5132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The POSIX specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) states that

> ```
> A line is a sequence of zero or more non-<newline> characters plus a terminating
> <newline> character.
> ```

The behaviour of `grep` is the expected one. It adds the missing trailing newline character to the [`incomplete line`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195).

This way:

```bsh
$ cat file
# This is a commentary
aaaaaa
# This is another commentary
bbbbbb
cccccc

$ od -c file
0000000   #       T   h   i   s       i   s       a       c   o   m   m
0000020   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n   #
0000040   T   h   i   s       i   s       a   n   o   t   h   e   r
0000060   c   o   m   m   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   b   b   b   b   b
0000100   b  \n   c   c   c   c   c   c  \n
0000111

$ truncate -s -1 file

$ od -c file
0000000   #       T   h   i   s       i   s       a       c   o   m   m
0000020   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n   #
0000040   T   h   i   s       i   s       a   n   o   t   h   e   r
0000060   c   o   m   m   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   b   b   b   b   b
0000100   b  \n   c   c   c   c   c   c
0000110

$ od -c <(grep '.' file)
0000000   #       T   h   i   s       i   s       a       c   o   m   m
0000020   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   a   a   a   a   a   a  \n   #    
0000040   T   h   i   s       i   s       a   n   o   t   h   e   r    
0000060   c   o   m   m   e   n   t   a   r   y  \n   b   b   b   b   b
0000100   b  \n   c   c   c   c   c   c  \n
0000111
```