# Read the files in shell script doesn't print out anything?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, text

I am trying to read a file from shell script line by line. Below is my file content -

```
hello=world
```

And below is my shell script that I have written -

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
       echo "$line"
    done < test.txt
```

But somehow whenever I am running from my cygiwn terminal, I don't see any result printing out on the console -

I run it like this -

```
$ sh read.sh
```

And it doesn't print out anything. And I am not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of that file? Many Windows editors don't put one. What happens with a two-line file? Also, does the script have Unix line endings?

Comment: Do we need a new line at the end of that file? After putting a new line in that file, it started working somehow..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the unix world, a newline is a line terminator, not a line separator. A text file consists of a series of lines, each of which is terminated by a newline character. This is a linefeed character (character number 10, which can be represented as `LF`, `^J`, `\012`, `\x0a`, `\n`, …). See [What's the point in adding a new line to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file/18789#18789)

In particular, every non-empty text file ends with a newline character. Windows sometimes works differently: in some applications, (but not all! Windows is not consistent), a CR LF sequence (carriage return, line feed, a.k.a. `^M^J`, `\015\012`, `\x0d\x0a`, `\r\n`, …) separates lines, so a file that ends in CRLF is a file that ends in a blank line. So beware when you use a Windows editor to edit files that are meant to be used elesewhere:

- They add this extra CR character before the newline character, which some unix applications (in particular shells) treat as an ordinary character, part of the line.
- They make you believe that there's a blank line after the last newline character, whereas the last newline actually terminates the last line.

If a file is not empty and does not end in a newline, it isn't a well-formed unix text file. Some applications react by ignoring the last partial line, or by truncating it. That's what's happening here: you passed an incomplete text file to bash, and it's ignoring the last, incomplete line.