# Logical all/any in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run a series of tests (each on a different PID), and derive a successful status only if all tests exit successfully. Something like

```
check $PID1 && check $PID2 && check $PID3
```

but for an indeterminate number of tests. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In what format is your "indeterminate" command list?

Comment: Do you want to continue running the tests if one fails, or exit immediately?

Comment: The title ("all/any") is a little broader than the body ("all"); which one do you need?

Comment: I need `all` in this case; just interested in both (and of course negating `any` can give the effect of `all`)

Comment: What is tag "test" doing? The definition seems clear...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That shouldn't be too hard to write out as a loop:

```
pids=(1025 3425 6474)
check_all() {
    for pid in "$@"; do
        if ! check "$pid"; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
}
check_all "${pids[@]}"
```

Like the chain of commands linked with `&&`, the function will stop on the first failing `check`.

Though do note that I replaced your variables `PID1`, `PID2` etc. with a single array. Bash could iterate over variables whose names start with a particular string, but arrays are just more convenient. (Unless those variables come from the outside of the script through the environment where you can't pass proper arrays.)

Also, I hard-coded the `check` command in the loop here. You could pass distinct commands for the function to run, but that's ripe with issues with word splitting and quote handling. (See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373).)

Comment: You could also use a subshell declaration for the function: `check_all() ( ... )` and then add  `set -e`, then you can get rid of the whole `if ! ... ; then return 1; fi` part and just `check $pid` as only command in the for-loop. ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302061)).

Comment: @pLumo, nah, I like being explicit about the test and exit/return. And the subshell isn't needed for anything else so I just like to avoid it on principle. :P `check "$pid" || return 1` would be one alternative, of course.

Comment: Thank you, putting the PIDs in the array and returning from a function cleans up the control flow a lot. My loop was getting the PIDs from a file with `read` (left this out of the question for obvious reasons), and I was trying to exit the loop with the success status in `$?`... much too complicated.

Comment: @alexis, yeah, getting a sane status out of a loop is hard since `return` just sets the exit status to zero... But you could wrap the `while read...` inside a function too and bypass the whole array. That is, if you only need the list of PIDs once.

Comment: I hadn't realized `read` has an exit status! Thanks for that tip too :-)

Comment: @alexis, eh? I wonder how you did `read` the PIDs then. :) Anyway, about the exit status of `read`, note that it's picky about newlines, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478732/170373

Comment: If you run this intensely the expansion is a weak point. Can get very slow. If check is some tiny check, and check_all is frequently called with any number of pids, this really matters.

Comment: @rastafile, what expansion? What do you mean with "running intensely"? Also, if you have a better way, not prone to "getting very slow", you're free to suggest one, or write an answer of your own.

Comment: But i did write one, have you not seen? 22h ago -- I mean this `for pid in "$@"` expansion. Look at the Q. An "endless" row of PIDs going through only one single test. COULD be very high turnover. I did a prime numbers program just lately in bash. Tried different "tricks" but it gets very slow -- must be the loop-the-array-elements thing. Benchmark result is about 20s to 0.05s (bash vs perl, up to 30'000)

Comment: @rastafile, yes, if you pass a very large number of arguments to a function, it will take some time to process them all. But if you do have a large amount of items to process, a shell script will be slow just because of the shell, too, and you probably should implement your program using some other tool. Doubly so if the task at hand (the `check` command) involves launching external programs, and some other tool lets you avoid that. Even so, I doubt the expansion of an array is going to be the slow part.

Comment: hmm...I think you mix a few things up. These are two extremes (mass testing of PIDs, "elaborate" array puhing-and-looping of found prime numbers). My solution is perfect for the first: input stream, no additional process, even more usable as it is a one liner. You made a standerd loop with exit status. Not tailor made. But then again, this Q is not well specified. At least we all agree on that.

Comment: @rastafile, yes, I made a standard loop, which, in my opinion, fits the issue presented in the question nicely. I don't see any relevant problems with the solution in sensible use cases. I also addressed your concern of slow running by proposing the use of a another tool, which again, in my opinion, would be the best solution. Any any case, I don't expect slowness to be an issue since the question presents a case of _only_ three PIDs. Also, I find the question as presented clear enough on the relevant parts. Please do not presume to know my opinions on matters like that, or otherwise.

Comment: @ilkkachu "I wonder how you did read the PIDs then." Sort of like this: `while true; do; read PID ; ... done < pid.file` (with some conditionals leading to a `break` in the `...`). This reads the input line by line. `read` will assign an empty value after the inputs run out, so I had to check for that, etc. etc.

Comment: @alexis, yep. As long as it works, it's not _wrong_.

Comment: Well it didn't quite work, hence this question! :-D

Answer (score 4):

You could put it in a subshell with exit-on-error ( `-e` ):

```
pids=(1025 3425 6474)
(
    set -e
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        check "$pid"
    done
)
echo $?
```

Alternatively, you can use `|| exit 1` instead of `set -e`:

```
pids=(1025 3425 6474)
(
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        check "$pid" || exit 1
    done
)
echo $?
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
parallel -j0 check ::: $pid1 $pid2 $pidN &&
  echo all succeeded
parallel -j0  '! check' ::: $pid1 $pid2 $pidN &&
  echo all failed
parallel -j0 --halt soon,success=1 check ::: $pid1 $pid2 $pidN &&
  echo one succeeded
parallel -j0 --halt soon,fail=1 check ::: $pid1 $pid2 $pidN ||
  echo one failed
```

It will run the checks in parallel. Replace `soon` with `now` if you want running checks to be killed as soon as we know the result.

If you have the PIDs as output from a pipe (one per line):

```
pid_generator | parallel -j0 check && echo all succeeded
```

`parallel` gives one value to `check` and runs as many `check` as possible in parallel (`-j0`).

If the server does not have `parallel` installed, run this on a machine that *has* `parallel` installed:

```
parallel --embed > new_script
```

Edit `new_script` (the last 5 lines) and copy the script to the server.

Comment: And what about the "indeterminate" input? And what if check takes only one argument?

Comment: Wow, parallel. I'd probably go for this solution if I was already using parallel, but in this case a pure-bash approach is better (don't want extra dependencies on the target server...)

Comment: @alexis Try `parallel --embed` for that.

Comment: @rastafile `check` is only called with one input. You can put as many `$pids` as you want.

Comment: @OleTange I do not know how many PIDs there are. Question of not knowing, not of not being able to put enough. "one input" is too monolithic. An input stream that finishes or breaks is more flexible. Up to the user to control the "finishing" (error or EOF). Your solution actually needs a helper loop or extension or xargs.

Comment: @rastafile How do you receive the PIDs?

Comment: @OleTange o I see you mean parallel feeds the PIDs to check one by one. Normally it's the other way round isn't it? "run the checks in parallel" --- this is VERY ambiguous: here **check is run serially in parallel**

Comment: How? In a very very unix way. File with newlines and ASCII integers. But you can plug my bare compound command (a `while` loop) to any INPUT stream, up to a process substitution from the right:  WHILE `< <(pid-generetor-indet.cmd)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100003/discussion-between-ole-tange-and-rastafile).

Answer (score 0):

A simple function could test each argument; if any fail, return from the function with a non-zero code:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

testall() {
  for test
  do
    sh -c "$test" || return 1
  done
}
```

With some example tests:

```
$ testall "echo 1" "echo 2" "false" && echo all OK
1
2
$ testall "echo 1" "echo 2" "echo 3" && echo all OK
1
2
3
all OK
$ testall && echo all OK
all OK
```