# Why the sed command is not replacing the pattern inside a shell script?

Tags: shell, sed, freebsd

I am trying to prepare a shell script to include several chained sed commands.

I am using `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD 12. Which seems to be POSIX compliant (see man page [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=&n=1)).

This is what I have tried, it can be clearly seen that the behaviour is not the expected one:

```
$ cat testfile.txt 
<TEST>

$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
        sed 's/<TEST>/FOO/' 
done <&0
$ cat testfile.txt | ./test.sh 

$ cat testfile.txt | sed 's/<TEST>/FOO/'
FOO

$
```

I guess I am missing something basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *reading* lines, but you're not doing anything with what you read. Try:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
        printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed 's/<TEST>/FOO/'
done <&0
```

Also you may want to change the `while read line` to

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
```

to ensure that you are reading everything as `cat testfile.txt | sed 's/<TEST>/FOO/'` would. See

- [Understanding “IFS= read -r line”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)
- [What does `while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]` mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478720/what-does-while-read-r-line-n-line-mean)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, while you *can* write complex scripts in shell, it is better to use a language designed for scripting, not interactive use. Python, Perl or Raku are my first ideas when doing something more complex than a few lines. Python is popular, and almost everywhere available, ditto Perl; Raku is an evolution/ground up redesign of Perl, not nearly as popular (yet?).