# HISTTIMEFORMAT messed up adb

Tags: bash, history, adb

I set up earlier this month `HISTTIMEFORMAT` cause I needed to see the time on some of the commands I previously used. However, I most likely messed something up with those commands, because every time I try to use adb for anything (adb kill-server eg.) I get the following error: `bash: /home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adbHISTTIMEFORMAT=%d%m%y: No such file or directory`. These are the commands that I used to setup `HISTTIMEFORMAT`:

```
 1032  20/05/22 19:17:45 echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d%m%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
 1033  20/05/22 19:17:46 history
 1034  20/05/22 19:19:17 source ~/.bashrc
 1035  20/05/22 19:19:19 history
 1036  20/05/22 19:20:22 echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
 1037  20/05/22 19:20:32 source ~/.bashrc
```

What exactly did I do wrong and how can I fix/revert it?

Comment: How do I fix that? I tried removing that line from the `bashrc` file, but it just removed the timestamp from the history command. The adb error is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis: your old `~/.bashrc` contained an [incomplete line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195) and the line was related to `adb`. Your command

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d%m%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
```

added *to* the line instead of adding *another* line. This behavior is [one of the reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664377/108618) the last line should be properly terminated.

My tests indicate an incomplete line in `~/.bashrc` is not ignored by Bash. You may have had an incomplete `alias …` line that worked. Your incomplete line might be:

```
alias adb='/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'
```

(maybe without the single-quotes) and after the first `echo … >> ~/.bashrc` it became:

```
alias adb='/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d%m%y %T "
```

(maybe without the single-quotes). The line neither defines the exact alias you wanted, nor affects `HISTTIMEFORMAT`. It's a complete line though, so your second `echo … >> ~/.bashrc` worked as intended and created a *separate* line that actually affects `HISTTIMEFORMAT`.

In a comment you wrote:

> I tried removing that line from the bashrc file, but it just removed the timestamp from the history command. The adb error is still there.

Removing the last line (i.e. the output of the second `echo`) without noticing that the previous line is contaminated (with the output of the first `echo`) would do exactly this. My hypothesis stands.

Check the last line of your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Your assumption was correct and this was exactly what was wrong with my `bashrc`. I have no idea why didn't I notice that when I opened the file earlier. Thank you!