# Remove three lines from file until a match

Tags: text-processing, perl

```
982
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

984
01:25:15,390 --> 01:25:18,484
( MAJESTIC MUSIC )
```

I want to delete three lines below `984` (inclusive). I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/.*\n.*\n\(.*\)//'
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the three last lines in the file or the there specific lines starting with `984` regardless of whether they are last or not?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Comment: I see you are working on text records. Generalizing your question: 1. Do you want to seamlessly eliminate record `984`, or other such records of your choice? Or do you want to retain the top line of each record (e.g. `984`) as a "title", and then delete the "body" of the record only? Such a method would leave all record numbers sequentially intact (982, 983, 984...).

Comment: FYI, perl has a [Subtitles](https://metacpan.org/release/Subtitles) modules for working with subtitles.  From the debian package (`libsubtitles-perl`) description: `This module provides means for simple loading, re-timing, and storing these subtitle files.  The module supports srt, sub, smi subtitle formats.  A command-line tool 'subs' for manipulation of subtitles files is included in this package.`  BTW, see also https://metacpan.org/pod/App::SubtitleUtils

Answer (score 3):

Using a `sed` that understands relative addresses (non-standard, but generally supported):

```
$ sed '/^984$/,+2d' input_file
982
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.
```

Or, with any `sed`:

```
sed '/^984$/{$!N;$!N;d;}' input_file
```

That is, on the match, append the `N`ext two following lines (if they exist) and `d`elete them altogether.

Answer (score 1):

### Like this:

##### In paragraph mode:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print unless /^984\b/' file
```

##### line by line:

```
$ perl -anE 'if ($F[0] == 984) { last } else { print }' file
```

##### slurping the whole file using regex ¹:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $& if /.*(?=\n^984)/ms' file
$ perl -gne 'print $& if /.*(?=\n^984)/ms' file # perl >= 5.36
```

##### Output

```
983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.
```

##### ¹ The regular expression matches as follows:

| Regex | description |
| --- | --- |
| `.*` | Match 0 or more of any character |
| `(?=` | Positive lookahead assertion |
| `\n` | Match a newline character |
| `^` | Match the start of the string |
| `984)` | Match the 4 characters `984` and close look-ahead |

Comment: Perl "paragraph mode" example will delete an internal record starting with `984`, but Perl "line-by-line" example deletes from the line containing `984` to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in paragraph mode (activated by `RS=<null>` and used when input records are separated by blank lines):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$1 != 984' file
982
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.
```

If you couldn't use paragraph mode for some reason (e.g. maybe those apparently empty lines between records actually contain non-printable chars we can't see) and you truly did just want to delete 4 lines starting from `984` then you could do this instead (but it's less robust, see below):

```
$ awk '$1 == "984"{c=4} !(c&&c--)' file
982
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.
```

See [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001) for related awk idioms.

Note that the first script is the most robust as it will ONLY match on exactly 984 on the first line after an empty line. You should include cases like:

```
950
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,984
this is bad

951
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
984 here is also bad

9841
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
this is also bad
```

in your sample input/output to flush out scripts that would falsely match on the 3rd line of the record instead of just on the first or would do a partial instead of full match on the number you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can use line like this:

```
awk '$0==984 {getline;getline;getline} {}1'  input_file >output_file
```

The idea is command `getline` read the next line from input stream. If we talk about subtitles you should skip this and next 3:

```
awk '$0==984 {getline;getline;getline;getline} {}1'  input_file >output_file
```

Comment: That chain of `getline`s would leave $0 set to the last successful call to getline so you'd get the 3rd or 4th line after 984 printed instead of deleted. YMMV with not testing the results of getline and obviously hard-coding as many calls to getline as lines you want to delete isn't ideal.

Comment: @EdMorton, if this is really subtitles the next line will be empty and should be deleted (it's not good to have more than one empty lines, but it's not catastrophe). You are right about hardcoding, but this is fast and dirty (and sample) way to do the work :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "subtitles", sorry. What I'm saying is that if you execute `$0==984 {getline;getline;getline} {}1` then at `1`, given the OPs sample input, `$0` will be populated with `( MAJESTIC MUSIC )` and so that line will be printed. You can solve that and the extra blank line problem by adding a `;next` after the last getline in each block. You could just do `for (i=1;i<=4;i++) getline` to avoid hard-coding 4 calls to getline and it's no less fast, just a bit less dirty :-)

Comment: @EdMorton, I see about the code. To clarify it work for me, yes, `for` will be possible improvement. About subtitles: think about movie/film and text on the bottom part of the screen which write what actors say (or any music/noise as text).

Comment: Oh, yeah, I can see that now. I thought it was something like a track of songs with titles.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put unless /^ 984 $/ fff *.chars == 0 ;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -ne '.put unless /^ 984 $/ fff {.chars == 0} ;'  file
```

The above code uses Raku's `fff` "flip-flop" operator, which detects a record starting with `984` and ending on a blank line (`.chars` equal zero). Note the above code makes no attempt to detect a blank line *before* `984`.

Sample Input:

```
982
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

984
01:25:15,390 --> 01:25:18,484
( MAJESTIC MUSIC )

985
01:25:18,485 --> 01:25:18,500
( END CREDITS )
```

Sample Output (1):

```
982
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

985
01:25:18,485 --> 01:25:18,500
( END CREDITS )
```

Raku provides a number of `fff` variants to leave either-or-both of the two recognition sequences in the return. They are `^fff` or `fff^` or `^fff^`. This reduces the need to use lookaheads/lookbehinds. For example, simply change `fff` in the above code to `^fff^` to get the following return:

Sample Output (2):

```
982
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

983
01:25:09,473 --> 01:25:10,978
Stay with me.

984

985
01:25:18,485 --> 01:25:18,500
( END CREDITS )
```

If you want/need to separate records first, `slurp` the file in all at once and simply split on `\n\n` consecutive newlines. Then the remainder of the code simplifies to the following, but unfortunately adds two blank lines to the very end of the file:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'for slurp.split("\n\n") { put $_ ~ "\n"  unless /^984 / };' file
```

Not to worry, see the first link below to use Raku for removing blank lines at the beginning/end of a file.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725227/227738
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org